# Query based on multiple keywords

Tags: 7, database

I have 5 nodes title with some keywords:

1. this is my node one with some keywords
2. this is my **second title** with some keywords
3. this is my another **title** with **second** keyword
4. this is my another **title second** keyword
5. this was my last node **title**

My search query is: "**second title**"

when i search with only **title** keyword, query return 2,3,4, and 5 well, but when i search **second title**, query return only 2. So, how can i extend my query to return nodes as 2,4,3 and 5 in the last position (since 5 has only one keyword match).

This is my query:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
         ->fields('n')
         ->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($_GET['Keywords']) . '%', 'LIKE')
         ->execute()
         ->fetchAll();
```

**Updated:**
search keywords can more then 2 words, but query should return as much words matches.

please help!

thanks.

Comment: Sanitize that input! Id advise using Search API + View with a fulltext search. Solr would be best fit for broadest yet relevant match.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for your quick reply, but here i don't use views and search api module. I created my search results page using custom module. And honestly i am not much expert to integrate search api module with my custom module. Have you any advice to integrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want db_or().

```
$or = db_or()->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like('second') . '%', 'LIKE')->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like('title') . '%', 'LIKE');
$results = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n')
  ->condition($or)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Yes, you updated answer working well, but have you any idea, how do i set orderBy parameters by maximum match?

Comment: maybe this answer will help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534668/3770000, but i can't figure out, how to use it with your code... could you please visit this?

Comment: That’s a different question.

Comment: what should i do? open a new question? I have already asked this question.

Comment: Go back to that question then please. Also since this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: sorry to say, this is partial answered! (i don't know, should i mark answered?) and i don't understand your text "Go back to that question then please" what did you mean?

Comment: No it's not. You asked how to structure your query to get the results you want, and I answered that, which you then stated solved that issue. If you don't want to mark it solved, fine. But I'll make note of your name and make sure to not answer your questions in the future.

Comment: i don't mean that. But i don't understand, what should i do. So, i asking you that "what should i do?" I marked your answer, but you just thread me, community should review this... And by the way, thanks for your help.